# inline this function, does make sense?

Tags: c++, templates, winapi, inline

I have the next member function:

```
template <typename T>
inline T Foo::Read(const DWORD addr) const                          // Passing by value.
{
    T buffer;
    ReadProcessMemory(m_processHandle, (LPVOID)addr, &buffer, sizeof(T), NULL);
    return buffer;
}
```

If I'm not wrong, when the compiler inlines a function, it avoids calling the function and put the code of the called function into the caller function.

So in the caller function (assuming an integer return type) I would want something like:

```
ReadProcessMemory(m_processHandle, (LPVOID)addr, &bufferOfTheCaller, sizeof(int), NULL);
```

I have three questions about this:

**1)** What would happen with the variable that we return from the function? 
Isn't the declaration of the variable **buffer** performed in run time?

**2)** In this case **ReadProcessMemory** is a huge function from the WinAPI, should the compiler still able to inline this function?

**3)** What is the difference between leaving the member function defined inside the class definition and declare it with the keyword **inline** outside the class definition? If I want to use inline keyword, Do I have to put the inlined function in the same file .h or?

Comment: That `inline` is completely redundant. The function is in the class declaration in the header, so it's *implicitly* inline. Besides that, `inline` doesn't mean what you think it does. It has *nothing* to do with actually inlining calls to the function, the compiler will do that or not depending on its own heuristics. It only has anything to do with linking and ODR.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, that `inline` is redundant but because it is a `template`. It is not in the class definition (prefix `Foo::` states that). I agree with the rest.

Comment: There is no function. That's a function template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to note that the `inline` keyword has nothing to do with inlining calls to the function.  All it does is allow the function to be defined in multiple translation units, as long as all of the definitions are the same.

What the `inline` keyword does is let you define a function in a header file that will be included in multiple translation units.  This may give the compiler a better opportunity to inline call to that function, since it has the full definition available in multiple translation units, but it is not a command or even a hint that you want the compiler to do so.  The compiler will decide on its own if it should or shouldn't inline a call to any given function.  There are compiler-specific extensions that you can use if you do want to force calls to a function to be inlined, but that is not what the `inline` keyword does.

---

With that out of the way, I'll add that the compiler inlining a function call doesn't change the rules of C++ at all.  It isn't a textual replacement, like a preprocessor macro.  The compiler will figure out how to insert the logic from the called function into the caller.  At that point, things like C++ variables don't really exist.  If your call looks something like this:

```
int someValue = myFoo.Read(someAddress);
```

then the compiler can easily transform that into something like this:

```
int someValue;
ReadProcessMemory(myFoo.m_processHandle, (LPVOID)someAddress, &someValue, sizeof(int), NULL);
```

due to the as-if rule.  Both of those snippets result in the same observable behavior, so the compiler can freely transform between them.

Answer (score 2):

> What would happen with the variable that we return from the function?

It will be destroyed, because the return value was discarded by the function call expression.

> Isn't the declaration of the variable buffer performed in run time?

Declarations happen at compile time.

> In this case ReadProcessMemory is a huge function from the WinAPI, should the compiler still able to inline this function?

If the compiler knows the definition of the function, then it **could** expand it inline. Whether it should, or whether it will do so depend on many factors. Size of a function is a heuristic that may affect the choice that the compiler makes.

> What is the difference between leaving the member function defined inside the class definition and declare it with the keyword inline outside the class definition?

In one case the definition is inside the class and in the other case it is outside. There is no other difference.

> If I want to use inline keyword, Do I have to put the inlined function in the same file .h or?

- If you want to define a member function inline, but want to define it outside of the class definition, then you must declare the function inline within the class definition - except a function template, which is implicitly inline.
- If you want to define the member function within the class definition, then you don't need to explicitly declare it inline; it will be so implicitly.
- If you want to not define the function inline, then you must define the function outside the class definition and must not use the inline keyword.

Answer (score 1):

> If I'm not wrong, when the compiler inlines a function, it avoids calling the function and put the code of the called function into the caller function.

Yes, but `inline` has little to do with that.

> 1) What would happen with the variable that we return from the function? Isn't the declaration of the variable buffer performed in run time?

The compiler, inlining or not, will have to reserve some space for `buffer`, typically on the stack.

In other words, there is no `bufferOfTheCaller`. If your function is inlined, `buffer` will be in the caller's stack frame; otherwise, it will be put in the callee's stack frame.

> 2) In this case ReadProcessMemory is a huge function from the WinAPI, should the compiler still able to inline this function?

It does not matter how big the implementation of `ReadProcessMemory` is, your code just performs a function call to it, which is tiny. An optimizing compiler is likely to inline your function.

> 3) What is the difference between leaving the member function defined inside the class definition and declare it with the keyword inline outside the class definition?

No difference.

> If I want to use inline keyword, Do I have to put the inlined function in the same file .h or?

The `inline` keyword is not about inlining. If you want to put the definition of a function in a header file, you will likely need `inline` to prevent redefinition errors.

Comment: so, no matter how big ReadProcessMemory is? The fact is that I'm going to use this function "Read" very often so avoid the calling, whether is tiny or not, should be better.

Comment: @EduardoG Not only it does not matter, your compiler does not even know how big `ReadProcessMemory` is, because it is a call to an external library.

Comment: @edu: `ReadProcessMemory` itself is insanely costly. Trying to optimize out the call instruction isn't ever going to make a noticeable or even measurable difference. If you need to optimize performance, measure first. Use a profiler.